# Tableau - YML file as data source

Tags: yaml, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I have a .yml file that contains some data the I need to use in my Tableau dashboard.  I didn't see that Tableau can directly use .yml as a data source (as it uses .xls, etc).  Does that mean do I need to convert my .yml to something supported by Tableau, or are there any other standard/more appropriate ways to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if your YML file contains data then you can add it as a text file. I added the file as a "TEXT" file and it displayed the data correctly

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you for the reply.  Though it can take it as a text file, it does not parse my yml correctly based on its structure - so looks like can't rely on it 100%.  Maybe I need to end up converting it to some more rigid structure like excel, xml, json before I use it.  Any other idea?  Thanks.